# Base Member Initialization vs Assigning default value in class declaration

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization, member

I'm reading about Base/Member Initialization in C++ and I don't understand really what's going on.  Consider the following example `Date` class:

```
// CLASS DECLARATION
class Date
{
    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    public:
        Date(int = 7, int = 4, int = 2012);     // CONSTRUCTOR
        Date(const Date&);                      // COPY CONSTRUCTOR
        void showDate();        // MEMBER FUNCTION TO DISPLAY DATE
};
```

One can create a `Date` object by:  `Date a;` which would assign the member variables of `a` to 7/4/2012.  Now what is the difference in doing a base member initialization such as the following:

```
// class declaration section
public:
    Date(int mo=7, int da=4, int yr=2012):month(mo), day(da), year(yr) {}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
// class declaration section
public:
  Date(int = 7, int = 4, int = 2012);  // prototype with defaults
// class implementation section
Date::Date(int mo, int da, int yr) : month(mo), day(da), year(yr) {}
```

Can someone please explain the differences between the two cases?  What's the difference and why would you do the second case?  Is it just another way to initialize default values in a constructor or is there more to it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is no difference. In the first case you are declaring AND defining the constructor in one step (thus the `{}` brackets). In the second case you are firstly declaring your constructor and then defining / implementing it. But the initializer list can only be in the definition, not declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments are substitued whenever a parameter is not explicitly passed. This means `void f(int a = 5)` can be called by writing `f()`, wich would be equivalent to `f(5)`. But you can also explicitly pass in a different value, for example `f(3)`.

However, both snippets in your example are not really equivalent, because the constructor `Date(int mo=7, int da=4, int yr=2012)` could as well be called with `Date(5)` which would be equivalent to `Date(5, 4, 2012)`.

EDIT: Oh sorry, you explicitly asked for the difference in the implementation. The default parameters are just used in the declaration, because the default values have to be passed in at the call site, where the implementation might not be visible (ie if defined in another translation unit/.cpp file).

Answer (score 1):

I see the only difference that functions including constructors that are defined in the class definition are inlined by default.
The second case allows you to separate declarations and definitions.